# Complex number as a vertex of equilateral triangle

Tags: complex-numbers

The complex number 'a' is defined as a=(sqrt3)/4+i*1/4 . a is positioned in the complex plane s.t. the complex numbers 'a', 'b'and 'c' are the vertices of an equilateral triangle which has the origin as its centre of rotational symmetry. Find the values of 'b' and 'c', the other two vertices.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! I think you’ll find the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) very helpful $\ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Write $a=\frac{\sqrt 3}{4}+\frac i4$ in polar coordinates.